# What is the word for a combination of a task and the time when the task should be executed?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a triplet of {auditor, task, time}. What is the single word for the combination of {task, time}?

The context: Scheduling optimization for financial auditors.

Example sentence: The optimization problem can be represented as a graph with auditor nodes on the left and ___ nodes on the right.

*Assignment* is likely not a good choice, because I am already using it to express that a worker does the task.
Similarly, I am already using *engagement* to describe a set of tasks. *Activity* fells to be at the same level as task. *Shift* does not feel to be appropriate because sometimes the task takes 1 hour and sometimes it stretches 10 days.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Because this board focuses on English as a medium of communication, single-word requests need to be set in a sentence/paragraph context. Please [edit] your question to supply such a context.

Comment: When you say *time*, do you mean *start time* or *duration*?

Comment: I mean start time.

Comment: @user824276 Are you sure you mean start time and not finish time?

Comment: @RichardKayser In my case, it is the start time. But if it helps, the problem could be rephrased to use finish time.

Answer (score 0):

How about **schedule**? From Lexico:

> [**schedule**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/schedule): A plan for carrying out a process or procedure, giving lists of intended events and times.

An audit is a process or procedure with an associated schedule, i.e., list of tasks and times.

**Addendum**: Based on the comment exchange below, I think the best word is **assignment**. Your example sentence:

> The optimization problem can be represented as a graph with auditor nodes on the left and **assignment** nodes on the right.

Here **assignments** pertain to the **assignments** of individual auditors, with each **assignment** consisting of a task and start time. All you need to do is come up with a word other than **assignment** to "express that a worker does the task", presumably one of your workers, not one of the auditors. You could use a word such as *lead* or *task lead* to convey that concept.

Comment: Yes. But how should I can call a single {task, time} instance (not a list of tasks and times)?

Comment: @user824276 What does your example sentence mean? In particular, what does *node* mean? The only word that would seem to fit your example is *auditee*, but I don’t see the relationship between that and {task, time}. Are you looking for a work like *element*?

Comment: The hierarchy of terms that I use is: engagement at the auditee > phase of engagement (e.g.: interim or final) > specific task that an auditor has to do during the phase (e.g.: data collection, analytics or management).
I model the problem like a bipartite graph. Auditors are vertices on one side. Task with their starting time are vertices on the other side. And whenever there is an edge between an auditor an a task with its starting time, it means that the auditor was assigned to the task and starting time. Currently I just use graph terminology for {task, time}: sink.